# Multidimensional Arrays via ajax to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, jquery

Ok seriously struggling here. I am having some problems trying to send a multdimensional array to PHP via ajax. Here's what I have been trying:

To simplify rather than copy paste a wall of code:

```
    peoplearray[0]  =  [name] => 'john'
                       [age]  => '28'
                       [sex]  => 'Male'
    peoplearray[1]  =  [name] => 'julie'
                       [age]  => '20'
                       [sex]  => 'Female'

    main_array['item'] = 'x';
    main_array['something'] = 'x';
    main_array['another'] = 'x';
```

I want to get this to php via `post`. I figured I may aswell just join them together as I am multidimensional anyway thus :

```
    main_array['peoplearray'] = peoplearray;
```

now to do the ajax:

```
// var data = JSON.stringify(main_array);

var send = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "theurl",
        data: {data:main_array} //I do change this `main_array` when using the above stringify!
});


send.done(function(msg) {
console.log(msg);
})
```

in PHP I am just doing the following right now:

```
$data= $_POST['data'];
print_r($data);
```

in firebug: `(an empty string)`

when I have the `var data = JSON.stringify(main_array);` uncommented I get the following: `[][`

if i add `$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);` to the php I get:

```
Array ( )
```

Basically the `main_array` I realise does not need to be an array and so I can get that stuff across no problem but what I need to do is get the `peoplearray` over so that I can do some `foreach` etc... with it in php.  Any help would be much appreciated I am sure I am just being stupid!

EDIT: The reasoning behind this is that `peoplearray` could have 0 or 100 entries so I just need to get it to php so I can `foreach` it to do the DB inputs. If there is a better approach I would be very grateful to hear it as I am still pretty new to this.

EDIT: Thanks to Nicola's answer everything is passing fine except the important part which is mainarry.peoplearray  - it is not appearing in the the return `console.log` and I cant access it in PHP. Any solutions on this or do I have to put the foreach intelligence in the javascript and just send everything individually?

Comment: can you post the entire JS function that makes the ajax request? if you use console.log(main_array) (before calling $.ajax) what does it show in firebug?

Comment: I am getting the correct result with console.log(main_array) when doing it before the JSON.stringify. After the JSON.stringify I get: []. As far as the ajax that is all I am doing currently. In fact it is the only true copy and paste! Just to get to this point has taken me forever debugging arrays in Chrome is a no no I have just found out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by keeping the `peoplearray` seperate.

So I did as Nicola said and created `mainarray` as an object ie. declaring with curlies: `{}`

The `peoplearray` I left as an array ie declaring with `[]`, however then `name,age&sex` fields I created as an object ie. {} and then `.push()` them into the the `peoplearray`.

Then the ajax looked as follows:

```
var send = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        url: "theurl",
        data: {data:main_array, people:peoplearray} 
});
```

then with the PHP everything is available in the $_POST, and if you

```
echo json_encode($people); //or whatever var name it is stored as in the php
```

the objects ie `name,age,sex` properties are shown in the

```
send.done(function(msg) {
console.log(msg);
})
```

Comment: This should have worked also by keeping them toghether, but it's a good solution

Comment: Yeah for some reason both the post and return was showing as null when I had an array inside the object or an array inside an array which is why I had to split them and make sure each 'person' was an object inside the `peoplearray`. Many thanks for your help Nicola.

Answer (score 7):

First of all `main_array` is not an array but an object because in javascript there are no associative arrays and for this reason

```
main_array['peoplearray'] = peoplearray;
```

is equivalent to

```
main_array.peoplearray = peoplearray;
```

and you should declare main_array like this

```
var main_array = {};
```

then try to change your function like this:

```
var send = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        url: "theurl",
        data: {data:main_array} 
});
```

and server side

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$data= $_POST['data'];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the answer. I realise I have a missing fundamental understanding of the object/array which I need to fill in. This works great but I lose the peoplearray in the returned object despite it showing before. Also how do I access each property on the php side?